# Java method works fine alone, but fails when called in another method

Tags: java, methods

I am taking this [Java course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/java-programming) with Duke Uni on Coursera. We are using BlueJ.
The data used is a csv with 10 rows and 3 cols.
[image]

I have a method that works fine alone called getRank, it effectively just gives me the line number of a name I want in a csv. The tweak is that Males and Females are in the same column, so it starts with females, and then it comes to males, so I need to restart the line count for males when I reach them to get the correct rank (i.e. Sophia has rank 1, Jacob also has rank 1). The working method code is:

```
public int getRank (int year, String name, String gender) {
    String filename = "yob"+year+"short.csv";
    FileResource fr = new FileResource(filename);
    int rank = -1;
    int count = 0;
    int first_female = 0;
    
    for (CSVRecord rec : fr.getCSVParser(false)){
        count += 1;
        if (rec.get(1).equals("F")){
            first_female += 1;
        }
        
        if (rec.get(1).equals(gender) && rec.get(0).equals(name)){
            rank = count;
        }
    }     
    if (gender == "M"){
        rank = rank - first_female;
    }
    return rank;
}
```

But now I am trying to make another method called getTotalBirthsRankedHigher, which uses the third column in the data to make a cumulative sum for all names with ranks higher than the input name (so Ethan should have 8+7 = 15, bc Jacob & Mason are higher ranked, so we sum them).

The method I wrote calls getRank() but getRank is not discriminating between males and females anymore, so I am having mistakes when inputing a male name. The code is:

```
public void getTotalBirthsRankedHigher (int year, String name, String gender){
    int higher_births  = 0;
    int names_rank = getRank(year, name, gender);
    String rec_name = "";
    String rec_gen = "";
    int current_record_rank = 0;
    String filename = "yob"+year+"short.csv";
    FileResource fr = new FileResource(filename);
    for (CSVRecord rec : fr.getCSVParser(false)){
        rec_name = rec.get(0);
        rec_gen = rec.get(1);
        current_record_rank = getRank(year, rec_name, rec_gen);
        System.out.println(year + rec_name + rec_gen + current_record_rank);
        if (rec.get(0) != name && rec.get(1).equals(gender) && names_rank > current_record_rank){
            higher_births += Integer.parseInt(rec.get(2));
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println("The total number of births higher than " + name + " in the year: " + year + " is "+ higher_births);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `if (gender == "M")` is not how to compare strings in Java.

Comment: @khelwood yes I just realized that it's .equals() that works here.
I was confused cuz it worked alone but not with invoking another method.